# How do I check in Java whether two references are holding the same object?

Tags: java

I am looking for a Java equivalent of pointer-comparison in C/C++.

Suppose I am invoking a getSomething() method of an object of a class from a third-party. How do I know if the implementation of the getSomething() is just returning the **same instance** everytime or returning a different instance of the object? 
I am **not** looking to check whether two objects are identical, but need to check if they are the same instance or not. The motivation is, if the 3rd party implementation is creating a new instance everytime, probably I can optimize my code by not invoking the method everytime. Assume getSomething() is invoked by me 1000s of times a second at run-time

From what I read from various articles, I shouldn't rely on hashCode(). In that case what is the way to do this?

Comment: This is what `==` does

Comment: object1 == object2 ?

Comment: Just `o1 == o2` should work.

Comment: Thanks. So, there is no way to override == operator in Java. If that is the case, that solves my problem.

Comment: Java has no operator overring available to the programmer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reference types are "pointing to" the same object, when they are equivalent according to the `==` (identity) operator.

---

The question says:

> I am not looking to check whether two objects are **identical**, but need to check if they are the **same instance or not** *(emphasis mine)*

You actually mixed equality with identity (as I did initially in the answer). Being the same instance *is identity*. Being the same value is *equality*.

Answer (score 2):

The `==` operator compares the values held by the two operands.  If the operands are primitive, the actual values are checked for equality.  If the operands are of object type, then `==` checks for equality of identity, functioning in this role just like Python's `is` keyword.

Note that there is bit of fudginess caused by autboxing and autounboxing between primitive and wrapper object types.

Answer (score 1):

== double equal operator are use to check whether  two reference variable hold the same object or not.
Eg.

```
     String s1 = new String("hello");
     String s2 = s1;
     String s3 = new String("hello");
     System.out.println(s1==s2); // it prints true
     System.out.println(s1==s3); // it prints false
```

s1 and s2 pointing to the same object.
s3 holds newly created object and hence s1 == s3 prints false

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not looking for the `==`operator. To compare two instances of an object, for example, I use the equals() Object method. Here are two useful links about comparisons:

[java ==, equals(), compare(), compareTo()](http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~diam/java/online/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html)

[Javadocs equals() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

Comment: He explicitly wants to check whether the instances are the same object for performence reasons, not whether they are equal to one another.

Answer (score -1):

You can use == operator to compare two objects if they are having same reference or not.